# Removing the own MovieClip through its class block

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a ship game and I'm having an problem to get opponents fading as well.

Well, these opponents (like ships) has an class. In this class I do a interval to make its children fly to left (*changing X per velocity number choosen on fourth argument in the function for adding enemies (*`addOpponent(opponentX, opponentY, opponentType, opponentVelocity)`) and, when any of them has coordinate X smaller than -25, must be removed, through *class* block of itself.

```
package  {

import flash.display.*
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.utils.setInterval;
import flash.utils.clearInterval;

public class opponentNave extends MovieClip {

    public function opponentNave(opponentVelocitySet) {
    var loopMoveClassicOpponentsNave:uint = setInterval(movingClassicOpponentNave, 58);

        function movingClassicOpponentNave() {
            if (x < -25) {
                clearInterval(loopMoveClassicOpponentsNave);
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            } else {
                x -= opponentVelocitySet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm using `this.parent.removeChild(this)`. I'm getting a error when the opponent X is smaller than -25, and it's on that time I want to remove the opponent child.

Comment: What error are you getting?  It should work so long as `this` hasn't been previously removed.   `if(this.parent) this.parent.removeChild(this);`  You should use a `Timer` instead of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` - or better yet an `ENTER_FRAME` handler.    The issue, is likely that your interval is running faster than your frame rate (which can have other problems) - also, don't use inline functions like that

Comment: Then could I use the `ENTER_FRAME` to make this works? Really if this go works, I'm grateful... I will try to do this, thanks. :o) Really some rounds I'm using timers, the errors are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would refactor this: (see code comments)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class opponentNave extends MovieClip
    {
        //create a class scoped variable for the velocity
        private var velocitySet:Number;

        public function opponentNave(opponentVelocitySet)
        {
            //set the velocity var
            velocitySet = opponentVelocitySet;

            //wait for this object (opponentNave) to be added to the display before doing anything display oriented
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage, false, 0, true);

        }

        private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
            //run a function every frame tick of the application's fps
            //this is best for things that are display oriented instead of time based ways like Timer or Intervals
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            if (x < -25){
                if (this.parent) this.parent.removeChild(this);
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                x -= velocitySet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```